# Why doesn't this use of sed command work?

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I'm have a bash script that I use to manipulate files on a computation cluster.

The files I am trying to manipulate are of the format:

```
beadSize=6.25
minBoxSize=2.2
lipids=1200
chargedLipids=60
cations=0
HEAD=0
CHEAD=-2
BODY=2
TAIL=3
ION=-1
RHO_BODY=10
RHO_TAIL=14
tol=1e-10
lb=7.1
FTsize=8
ROUNDS=1000000
ftROUNDS=10
wROUNDS=1000
dt=0.01
alpha=1
transSize=0.15
transSizeZ=0.0
ionsTransSize=2.8
ionsTransSizeZ=2.8
rotateSize=0.18
volSize=8
modSize=0.0
forceFactor=2
kappaCV=0
sysSize=26
zSize=300
iVal=1
split=0
randSeed=580
```

I call a function inside a loop:

```
for per in $(seq 70 -5 5); do
    for seed in {580..583}; do
        for c in {"fs","fd","bfs","bfd"}; do
            let count=$count+1
            startJob $per $seed $c $count
        done
    done
done
```

and the lines I use to manipulate:

```
  let n=$1*12
  echo $n
  cat trm.dat | sed '/memFile*/d' | sed '/rStart*/d' | sed '/test*/d'| sed 's/modSize=[0-9.]*/modSize=0.0/' | sed 's/chachargedLipids=[0-9]*/chargedLipids="$n"/' | grep char #> propFile.dat
```

for `$per=15`, for example,  I expect `$n==180`. However when I run the script I see:

```
180
chargedLipids=120
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Note*
I have also tried to use:

```
sed "s/chachargedLipids=[0-9]*/chargedLipids=$n/"
```

With the same result.

Comment: The command line ends with a  ... comment. You have to quote the "#": `... |grep char \#`. Do you really have a file named '#'? Shouldn't this be just `grep -v \#` or something?

Comment: I think you should strip down the question, this is somewhat complicated and most of it does not relate to sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chacharged` != `charged`, and the final sed is doing nothing.  With single quotes, you would expect to see the literal text `chargedLipids="$n"` in your output if a replacement was being made.